# How To Access Minecraft Community Wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

How do I get to the arquade community wiki?

Comment: Why should this be closed? It seems fairly obvious to me he just doesn't understand what "community wiki" means here

Answer (score 6):

"Community Wiki" just means that that answer is not attributed to any one author, and thus can be expanded on by anyone. It also doesn't award reputation to anyone. There is not actually a wiki on the Arqade site.

Comment: More info can be found on [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) help page

Comment: It might be worth expanding on 'Tag Wikis' too.